# Google Drive API integration with Android

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-api-client

I'm working on an android app which should connect google drive to download some data, I've downloaded googledrive sample app, but not able to find Drive GoogleAccountCredential classes as I need to import those to access google drive, I've added google play services library to my app.

I've followed this http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/connecting-to-google-drive-from-an-android-app and used the same src code.

[image]

[image]

[image]

How can I solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

replace

GoogleAccountCredential crd = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE); because Arrays.asList is deperecated (Naresh Bandaru 9985649940)

Comment: yea I will, still my question is not answered, it is a configuration issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do you import GoogleAccountCredential and DriveScopes classes? I think that Eclipse don't know these classes.